# Is it possible swap two elements of a const vector passed as parameter in a function func(say) in c++ ex: vector<int>func (const vector<int>&v) {}?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, constants

can we swap the elements of vector v without using any extra space and return v?

```
vector<int>func(const vector<int>&v)
{
   //write your code here
}
```

Comment: It is possible by casting away the `const`-ness of the object but you are treading on dangerous waters. There is a reason why he input is a `const` object. How do you justify swapping its elements?

Comment: Why are you trying to modify a const vector? It's const, it's not meant to change.

Comment: You need to copy the vector to return it. You'll be allocating memory regardless.

Comment: @RSahu 
well I was asked this question in a mock interview where I was provided with a function and this const vector as a parameter and the main function was hidden. I knew the most optimized solution that included swapping elements of that given vector as a part of the solution and pseudocode for that solution was being provided after the interview and the logic was same as of mine.
But I knew that these elements can't be swapped as the vector was casted as const So, I justed wanted to know if there is some possible way that I don't know about.

Comment: @RSahu That's a really loose definition of "possible" right there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function returns the vector by value, which means it makes a copy of the input. Hence, you can make the copy explicitly, modify the copy and return it. E.g.:

```
vector<int> func(vector<int> const& v) {
    vector<int> u(v);
    // modify u.
    return u;
}
```

One could also make the caller copy the argument `vector<int> func(vector<int> u)`, but that disables return value optimization and hence 2 copies of the vector are made (one for function parameter another for return). See [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) for full details:

> In a return statement, when the operand is the name of a non-volatile object with automatic storage duration, **which isn't a function parameter or a catch clause parameter**, and which is of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type. This variant of copy elision is known as NRVO, "named return value optimization".

To modify the vector in-place without copying, the function must take a reference to non-const vector:

```
vector<int>& func(vector<int>& v) {
    // modify v.
    return v;
}
```

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin . Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for:)